# Using DataTemplateSelector with CollectionView for Alternating Row Colors is Not Working

Tags: maui

I am trying to use DataTemplateSelector to create alternating row colors in a CollectionView. The CollectionView is currently working without the DataTemplateSelector so I know my service is working to retrieve the data and my data bindings work to display the data. However, when I try to use the DataTemplateSelector I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The problem seems to be that the "EvenTemplate" and "UnevenTemplate" variables are not getting set in the following:

```
public class AlternateColorDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate EvenTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate UnevenTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            return ((ObservableCollection<Monkey>)((CollectionView)container).ItemsSource).IndexOf(item as Monkey) % 2 == 0 ? EvenTemplate : UnevenTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Here is the View:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Monkey"
                          x:Key="EvenTemplate">
              ...
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Monkey"
                          x:Key="UnevenTemplate">
              ...
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:AlternateColorDataTemplateSelector   
                   x:Key="alternateColorDataTemplateSelector"
                   EvenTemplate="{StaticResource evenTemplate}"
                   UnevenTemplate="{StaticResource unevenTemplate}" /> 
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource alternateColorDataTemplateSelector} "/>
```

And the ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys { get; } = new();
readonly MonkeyService monkeyService;
readonly IConnectivity connectivity;

        public MonkeyViewModel(MonkeyService monkeyService, IConnectivity connectivity)
        {
            this.connectivity = connectivity;
            this.monkeyService = monkeyService;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task GetMonkeys()
        {
            
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            try
            {
                IsBusy = true;

                var monkeys = await MonkeyService.GetMonkeys();

                if (Monkeys.Count > 0)
                    Monkeys.Clear();

                foreach (var monkey in monkeys)
                {
                    Monkeys.Add(monkey);
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get procedures: {ex.Message}");
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
            }

            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }

        }
```

When I debug, I see that the first row of data has been passed to the AlternateColorDataTemplateSelector but both EvenTemplate and UnevenTemplate are null as seen in the screenshots below. As soon as I "step into" the code an exception is thrown and I get the error.

[First Row passed to DataTemplateSelector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHtYE.png)

[EvenTemplate null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7qxi.png)

[UnevenTemplate null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6An4n.png)

Comment: `{StaticResource evenTemplate}` vs `<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Monkey"
                          x:Key="EvenTemplate">`. Your resource is named `EvenTemplate`. Capitalization matters.

Comment: That did it! Good eye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code in the View:

```
<local:AlternateColorDataTemplateSelector   
               x:Key="alternateColorDataTemplateSelector"
               EvenTemplate="{StaticResource EvenTemplate}"
               UnevenTemplate="{StaticResource UnevenTemplate}" />
```